# i got an error when click search button

Tags: c#, mysql

when click search button it gives me this error (incorrect syntax near '43') 43 is the area id, i make sure that the area id is the same in all tables and gov id is the same too, here is the code i use

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Page.RegisterStartupScript("open", "<script language=javascript>alert('dd')</script>");
    //   Session["conection"] = "Data Source=MEDICONSULT;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True";
    Session["conection"] = "Data Source=MEDICONSULT;Initial Catalog=test1;Integrated Security=True";

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    connection = new SqlConnection((string) Session["conection"]);
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da_1 = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    da_1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
    command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    string sql1 = "select Address1,provname from sites where cat_id=2";

    if (addressTextBox.Text != "")
    {
        sql1 = "SELECT provname,address1,LAT,LONG FROM site where cat_id=2 and provname like '%'+@provname+'%'";
        SqlParameter search = new SqlParameter();
        search.ParameterName = "@provname";
        search.Value = addressTextBox.Text.Trim();
        command.Parameters.Add(search);
    }

    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue != "0")
    {
        sql1 = " SELECT area, address1, provname FROM sites WHERE cat_id=2 and gov_id='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'";
    }

    if (DropDownList2.SelectedValue != "0" && DropDownList1.SelectedValue != "0")
    {
        sql1 = "SELECT area, address1,provname FROM sites WHERE cat_id=2 and gov_id='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "and area_id='" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
    }

    command.CommandText = sql1;
    da_1.SelectCommand = command;
    ds_1 = new DataSet();
    da_1.Fill(ds_1, "sites");

    searchResults.DataSource = ds_1;
    searchResults.DataBind();
    Label1.Text = ds_1.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 ? ds_1.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString() : "لا يوجد نتائج من البحث الذي ادخلته";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a single quotes `'` before `and` and at the and of the query.

```
 sql1 = "SELECT area, address1,provname FROM sites WHERE cat_id=2 and gov_id='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'"+ " and area_id='" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue+"'";
```

But I will surely say that please use parameterized query.

```
Sql1 = "SELECT area, address1,provname FROM sites WHERE cat_id=2 and gov_id= @gov_id and area_id= @area_id";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql1, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gov_id", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@area_id", DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [*parameterized queries*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) instead.

This kind of string concatenations are open for *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks. And most commanly, you can forget some single quotes (`'`) in this kind of concatenations and finding where you forget these quotes would be really hard.

```
sql1 = "SELECT area, address1,provname FROM sites WHERE cat_id=2 and gov_id= @gov and area_id= @area_id";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql1, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gov", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@area_id", DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
```